The hat-check problem
Six men go to the theatre and leave their hats at the cloakroom.
During the play there is a power cut, the six men leave, but it's dark, so the hats are handed back to them at random.
Someone says: the probability that at least one of them gets his own hat back is greater than 50%.
Is this statement correct?

It can be shown that it is. In particular, the theory of derangement proves that the probability is ~63.2%.

But I have another question on this, which I do not know the answer to.

This problem is from a book I bought a few years ago. When I looked at the solution, it only stated that the probability was indeed greater than 50%, about 63.2%, but it did not provide a proof or even a conceptual justification. My question is: could one prove that the probability is > 50% without explicitly deriving a full formula?


Since the "another question" is the real question here (I suppose?) perhaps can make that the main question immediately after "Is this statement correct"

The statement is indeed correct, and, in fact, also correct for five or seven men. The statement (probability strictly greater than 50%) is correct for any $n$ men $n > 2$.

One particularly satisfying way to answer the second question would be to pair up the 6! outcomes in such a way that in every pair, at least one outcome involves someone getting their own hat back. Is there an easy way to do this?

@justhalf : fair point, but as this is a puzzling forum, I thought the original problem from the book should be stated first.

Yea, so that's why I wrote "immediately after"

Can you perhaps elaborate in comments on what is missing from existing answer attempts, or, rather, what is too much assumed in existing answers, because: you ask for answer to be without ...? Have a nice day!

@FirstNameLastName : I was sort of waiting for a consensus to be reached by this expert community, as I see some answers are followed by comments arguing that they are not formally valid, so I would not want to mark as accepted one that isn't. If you can identify an answer that is for sure correct, please advise. Otherwise I will just accept the one with most votes.

Here a pretty straightforward (hopefully) way to get a lower bound:

 Give out the hats one at a time. The first man has a $\frac{5}{6}$ chance to get the wrong hat. If he gets the wrong hat, choose the second man to be one whose hat is still available; he then has a $\frac{4}{5}$ chance to get the wrong hat. If he also gets the wrong hat, choose the third man to be one whose hat is also still available; he then has a $\frac{3}{4}$ chance to get the wrong hat. We don't care what happens to the last three men. We can't easily keep doing what we've been doing because it might be that the three hats we gave out belonged to the remaining three men, or it might not. But, the probability that the first three men in this method all got the wrong hats is $\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$. Thus, it is also probabilty $\frac{1}{2}$ that at least one of them got the right hat, and the inequality is strict because there is clearly some chance that at least one of the last three men gets the correct hat even if the first three were all wrong.


How do you ROT13(pubbfr gur frpbaq zna gb or bar jubfr ung vf fgvyy ninvynoyr) if you can't see the hats?

@JacobisonCodidact If every permutation of the hats is equally likely, it doesn't matter how we achieve this result, as the probability only depends on the fact that all the permutations are equally likely. You may need to convince yourself that all permutations are still equally likely.

@tehtmi I think equiprobability of permutations is a problem here, not a resolution - you've shown that under a certain configuration, the bound is 1/2, but we are not guaranteed to be in that configuration. We have a bound of 1/2 if we pick second and third people whose hats haven't been taken. But there's a 1/6 chance the second person we pick already had their hat taken, and that person does not have a 4/5 chance of getting their hat back. If we just hand out 3 hats to 3 people, we can't guarantee the second's hat isn't taken by the first - isn't the chance they all get wrong hats >1/2?

@NuclearHoagie Yes, for my reasoning to work, you need to choose who to go next. But there is no method of selection that can affect the equiprobability of permutations. Choosing the order does affect the probability that the second man gets the right hat (which is why I'm doing it), but it doesn't affect the probability that Bob gets the right hat. You may prefer to think of choosing the men after all the hats have already been assigned, although I think this is less intuitive.

@tehtmi That's the problem, we need to select a specific type of permutation among all possibilities, but have no way of choosing that, since all permutations are equally likely. The order does affect the probability the second man gets the right hat when assigning hats sequentially - if the 2nd man is the person whose hat is already taken, he has 0% chance of getting his own hat. Only if his hat isn't taken does he have a 20% chance. What happens when you give out the hats sequentially and do wind up giving Person #2's hat to Person #1?

@NuclearHoagie First examine Albert. Then examine the first of Bob and Charlie whose hat wasn't taken by Albert. Thus, either Bob or Charlie might be the "second man". Then, choose the first of Dan, Earl, and Fred whose hat wasn't taken by Albert or the second man.

@tehtmi I think it's the "choosing" terminology that's tripping me up - we give out hats in the dark and can't really look at the first hat to pick who to give the second hat to. I see what you're getting at, though, there does exist some set of 3 people for which they get the wrong hats don't take each other's hats, and that's all we need.

I made this diagram in case anyone is still confused, maybe it will help. https://imgur.com/a/z8S6NkV

This answer is on the right track but it is not a permutation problem, it’s pure combinatorics. Order doesn’t matter because the hats already allocated might (indeed will in the case of the last hat) be the current person’s hat. The chance that no one gets their own hat is (5/6)^6, so the chance that at least one person does is 1 - (5/6)^6.

@DaleM: I'm not sure what you think the distinction is between a "permutation problem" and "pure combinatorics". Do you disagree that after all the hats are distributed, the result is a permutation of the hats? Do you think that all these permutations are equally likely? If so, the chance of any event must be expressible with a denominator of 6! (which yours isn't). You can only multiply probabilities like you are doing if the events are independent which is not true here. What is the probability that exactly 5 people get their own hats? (Hint: It's impossible, but what does your method say?)

@tehtmi see my answer

@tehtmi you were right - see my new answer using a different technique.

If we knew the hats, then the probability that one of the first three gets the right hat using this algorithm is >= 1/2. If we don't know the hats, then there are still three men so that the probability of one getting the right hat is >= 1/2, we just don't know which ones.

@NuclearHoagie Think about it this way: you don't have to "choose" at distribution. You can choose afterwards. All 6 men are given a hat, leave in a random order… and you ask the first one out the door "did you get the wrong hat?" — chance 5/6. If yes, then ask the person whose hat it is to step forwards and retrieve their hat. Next, ask one of the remaining 4 or 5 people if they got the wrong hat out of the 5 remaining hats: chance 4/5. If yes, ask the hat's owner to retrieve it. This leaves between 2 and 4 people, and 4 unclaimed hats. Ask one person, with a 3/4 chance 'wrong hat'.

Nice answer for n=6

Here's a combinatorial argument. Let $A_0,A_1,A_2$ be the sets of permutations where exactly $0,1,2$ men get their own hat respectively.

 Pick any permutation in $A_0$, and pick any man. Let that man swap hats with whoever has his hat. This gives some permutation in $A_1\cup A_2$. There are $6|A_0|$ ways to do this.


 Now any permutation in $A_2$ gets counted exactly twice in this way: the man chosen must have been one of the two with his own hat, and he swapped with the other one. Each permutation in $A_1$ gets counted exactly $5$ times: the man chosen must have been the one with his own hat, and he could have swapped with any of the others.


 Thus $6|A_0|=5|A_1|+2|A_2|<5|\overline{A_0}|$.

This shows that the probability of no-one getting his own hat is less than $\frac{5}{11}$.

I don't think the first statement that we end up with 6|A_0| permutations is correct.  Suppose that the permutation has man A with man B's hat and then man B with man A's hat.  Then when either A or B swaps the hat on their head with their own hat we will end up with the same permutation.  So we have fewer than 6|A_0| resulting permutations.  I'm not sure if that affects the outcome.

@user23087 The $6|A_0|$ is not counting the outcomes but rather all the ways to pick a man from a permutation in $A_0$. (The counting comes later, and your observation is exactly the reason we see $2|A_2|$ in there.)

Looks like this generalizes to $\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$.

The percentage $63.2\%$ is immediately recognizable as $1 - 1/e$, suggesting a strong link to the Poisson distribution. Simulation shows that the probability falls from $2/3$ for $N=3$, and converges around $1 - 1/e$ for large $N$. What's going on?

An event which has a $1/N$ chance of success, when observed in $N$ independent trials, has a $1 - 1/e$ chance of succeeding at least once in the limit of large $N$. In the limit of many, many hats, we can basically treat the trials as independent and identically distributed - with arbitrarily many hats the first person has a 0% chance of picking the second person's hat, and the second person's $1/(N-1)$ chance of picking their own hat is indistinguishable from the first person's $1/N$ chance when $N$ is large. With a very large number of hats, everybody has a $1/N$ chance of getting their own hat, and treating the trials as independent, there's a $1-((N-1)/N)^N$ chance at least  one gets their own hat, converging to $1- 1/e$ for large $N$, or $63.2\%$.

This doesn't exactly prove the probability is $>50\%$ for $N=6$ specifically, but does provide an intuition about why it's $>50\%$ for a large number of hats. It's simple enough to list the permutations for $N=3$ to see the probability is $66.6\%$, and we converge to $63.2\%$ for large $N$, so it's intuitively reasonable to interpolate and conclude the probability is indeed $>50\%$ for $N=6$.

$N=6$ is not really large so a lot of the hidden argument may not apply.

@FirstNameLastName That's why I included the N=3 case. The selection of hats only becomes "more independent" by increasing N. The probability approaches the limit monotonically - it's >50% for N=3, and only increases from there, so it's also >50% for N=6. It actually turns out that as far as this problem is concerned, N=6 is indeed "large", as the probability is almost indistinguishable from the limit of an arbitrarily large number of hats. It turns out N=6 is almost no different from N approaching infinity.

This can be solved using the inclusion-exclusion principle to find the 6-th Derangement
Derangements are also called subfactorials and are notated $!n$, as a kind of complement to factorials which denote arrangements $n!$. The sequence of derangements is sequence A000166 in the OEIS.
Here's a simple paper on this exact technique for this exact problem.

 $$\begin{align}P_6&=1-{!6 \over 6!} \\&=1-{265 \over 720}\\&={91 \over 144}\\&= 0.6319\dot{4}\end{align}$$

This probability approaches $1-{1\over e}$ as $n$ approaches infinity. In fact, the proposition that the chance is greater than 50% is true for as few as 3 hats, and equal to 50% for 2 hats.
Proof without finding the exact solution
For one person, the chance that no one gets their own hat is 0 - there’s only one person and they own the only hat so they must get their own.
For two people, the chance that no one gets their own hat is 0.5. Either the first person gets the right hat or they don’t, both with a 50/50 chance. The second person must then get the only remaining hat.
From here, we can use the facts that the chance is derangements/arrangements and that the series of arrangements increases faster than the series of derangements so the chance is monotonically decreasing as $n$ increases. So, for $n>2$, the chance is always less than 0.5.

Welcome to Puzzle Exchange! Your answer is all fine as is the simple paper. But OP wanted to avoid explicitly deriving a full formula.

'faster' increase as you mention is certainly correct but might need some more formal explanation.


 Let's call the number of possible permutations for $n$ men/items ruling that out $f(n)$.  The first item can go to $n-1$ possible places. If item 1 goes to item 2's place, we'll have $n-1$ items left with 2 being guaranteed to be at the wrong position. Let's call such permutations $f(n, 1)$. We can also have two items (1 and 2 in this case) trade places.  $f(n) = (n-1)*f(n-1,1) = (n-1)(n-2)*f(n-2,1)$  $f(n)/(n-1) = f(n-1,1)$ $f(n-1)/(n-2) = f(n-2,1)$  $f(n) = (n-1)*[f(n-1)+f(n-2)]$  $f(2) = 1$  $f(3) = 2$ $f(4) = 9$  $f(5) = 44$ ...  $f(n) = (n-1)*[f(n-1)+f(n-2)]$  If $f(n-2)*(n-1) < f(n-1)$, then the probability decreases. If it's greater, it increases.  Let's compare $f(n)/n!, f(n-1)/(n-1)!$ and $f(n-2)/(n-2)!$. It amounts to comparing $n*f(n-1), (n-1)n*f(n-2)$ and $(n-1)*f(n-1)+(n-1)*f(n-2)$.  And when you compare the last one with each of the former two, it can be simplified to $f(n-1)$ and $(n-1)f(n-2)$ being on different sides both times, meaning $(n-1)*f(n-1)+(n-1)*f(n-2)$ is between $n*f(n-1)$ and $(n-1)n*f(n-2)$, and in turn, $f(n)/n!$ is between $f(n-1)/(n-1)!$ and $f(n-2)/(n-2)!$. So always $f(n)/n!<1/2$ if $n>2$, and the difference between 1 and that probability is then greater than 50%.


Sorry to ask: how exactly do you conclude last step $f(n)/n!<1/2$ if $n>2$ from previous knowledge? Feel free to edit your post to explain  rather than here in comments. Also your explicit f(n) formula derivation is perhaps what OP wanted to avoid. On the other hand: using the formula correctly as you do seems OK.

Because $f(n)/n!$ must be between $f(n-1)/(n-1)!$ and $f(n-2)/(n-2)!$, and $f(2)/2!$ is the largest possible value (the function gives smaller values than that for 3, 4, 5 and so on).

OK that is a nice visual argument to narrow down the values!, perhaps you could mention bigger value for $3$ (being $\frac{2}{3}$) as next barrier.

Here's a little python code that answers this questions.
import itertools


# Creating the complete state space of all hat permuatations
x = list(itertools.permutations(range(6), 6))

# Tracking each time someone gets their correct hat
myhat = 0

# For i in each event
for i in x:

    # For j in the number of individuals
    for j in range(6):

        # If the jth individual received their corresponding hat in this specific event, then myhat 
        # is increased by a value of 1 and we don't need to continue checking if the other individuals
        # in this particular event received their hat
        if j == i[j]:
            myhat+=1
            break

# This value should equal the probability of at least one individual receiving their hat back.
myhat/len(x)*100


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Your brute force program correctly confirms statement and it nicely does so for any $n>3$. But does it also prove the statement (as requested in OP)?

Here is another reasoning for probability > 1/2.

 A perhaps less known recursive equality:Let $p_n$ be the probability of a permutation being a derangement.Then $p_n = \frac{n-1}{n}\ p_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}\ p_{n-2}$.


 The above equality can be derived from the well known derangement recursive one, or can alternatively and independently be seen and proven as a (conditional) probability equality.

Then:

 Let $q_n = 1 - p_n$ be the probability of a permutation not being a derangement.i.e.: the probability under discussion that at least one of $n$ men gets his own hat back.One calculates : $q_n = \frac{n-1}{n}\ q_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}\ q_{n-2}$ (because $\frac{n-1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} = 1$).Which implies : $n\ q_{n} = (n - 1)\ q_{n-1} + q_{n-2}$.fwiw: This equation is equivalent to : $n\ (q_{n} - q_{n-1}) = (q_{n-2} - q_{n-1})$ which I happened to notice doing some brute force programming. This equation illustrates factorial fast convergence of $q_n$ (or $p_{n}$).

Now:

 We can proceed by induction(where we have $q_2 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $q_3 = \frac{2}{3} > \frac{1}{2}$ as induction starters):


 $n\ q_{n} = (n - 1)\ q_{n-1} + q_{n-2} > \frac{n - 1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n}{2}$   so:$q_{n} > \frac{n}{2\ n} = \frac{1}{2}$


 This holds for any $n > 3$ (and already so for $n = 3$).

